# Не получается загрузить некоторые файлы

Tags: apache, php

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не получается загружать нкоторые файлы через форму на сервер, т.е. например файлы с расширением .png нормально загружаются, а .jpg нет, как я понимаю они вообще даже во временную папку на загружаются. Вот форма и скрипт, который я использую:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="temp_my.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="50000" />
Файл: <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>

  $fileName = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"];

  $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];
  echo  $fileTmpLoc;
  echo '##############';

  echo $fileName;
  $pathAndName = "temp/".$fileName;

  $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathAndName);
 if ($moveResult == true) {
   echo "File has been moved from " . $fileTmpLoc . " to" . $pathAndName;
 } else {
    echo "ERROR: File not moved correctly";
  }
```

В чем может быть проблема? Может это из-за сервера? Использую Apache, Ubuntu

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: размер загружаемых файлов и настройки max_upload_filesize() сравните.

Comment: какие ошибки-то при этом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По началу я думал, что не работает move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathAndName);, хотя даже во временную папку файлы не поступали, сейчас после нескольких перегрузок сервераЮ всё заработало. Не знаю даже в чём именно проблема была, но сейчас её нет. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

В любой непонятной ситуации `var_dump`'ай `var_dump($_FILES)` и смотрите `$_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']`